# Как преобразовать ASCII в Unicode?

Tags: c#, .net, кодировка

Нашел на просторах интернета сей сниппет. У меня почему то отображаются вопросики в результатах.

```
var unicodeString= "Привет";
Encoding ascii = Encoding.ASCII;
Encoding unicode = Encoding.Unicode;

byte[] unicodeBytes = unicode.GetBytes(unicodeString);

byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.Convert(unicode, ascii, unicodeBytes);

char[] asciiChars = new char[ascii.GetCharCount(asciiBytes, 0, asciiBytes.Length)];
ascii.GetChars(asciiBytes, 0, asciiBytes.Length, asciiChars, 0);
string asciiString = new string(asciiChars);
```

Comment: Кодировка строки в `unicodeString` определяется кодировкой файла исходных кодов. Проверьте её через свойства файла в дереве проектов VS.

Comment: эммм. а как его просмотреть? У меня в контексном меню нет такого

Comment: @Arhad \u0420\u043e\u0441\u0441\u0438\u044f это какая кодировка?

Comment: Это гарантированно юникод, вне зависимости от кодировки файла исходных кодов.

Comment: @Arhad я хочу слово Привет преобразовать в юникод. В моем коде есть ошибки?

Comment: @Zevra Это юникодовские коды символов в слове "Россия".

Comment: @Zevra В Вашем коде нет ошибок, но есть непонимание, как соотносятся между собой кодировки Unicode и ASCII. Cлово "Привет" - и так юникод.

Comment: @Arhad: Это так для C++, но не для C#.

Comment: @VladD а что же из себя представляют строки в C# по вашему мнению? Официальные доки, говорят, что string это последовательность char, которая в свою очередь кодируется в UTF-16. https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/types-and-variables

Comment: @John: Внутреннее представление строк в C# не зависит от кодировки файла. Если страница в UTF-8 или там CP1251, символы, которые вы получаете при перечислении, будут всё равно будут в UTF-16. Для C++ это не совсем так.

Answer (score 4):

В C# строки не имеют кодировки. А вот массив байт может являться представлением строки в той или иной кодировке. Поэтому вопрос о кодировке появляется только при превращении строки в набор байт или набора байт назад в строку (а также записи в файлы и другие потоки, которые тоже являются набором байт).

Поэтому перекодировать строку не нужно, и бессмысленно.

В вашем случае вы получаете байты строки `"Привет"` в UTF-16 (переменная `unicodeBytes`), затем перекодируете их в ASCII (переменная `asciiBytes`). Проблема, однако, в том, что в кодировке ASCII вовсе нет кириллических символов, поэтому они заменяются на байты для знаков вопроса.

Далее вы декодируете дайте ASCII* в строку, и видите в ней закономерные знаки вопроса.

---

*кстати, это можно сделать и проще:

```
string asciiString = ascii.GetString(asciiBytes);
```

Comment: подскажите плиз что на что надо изменить

Comment: @Zevra: Ничего не надо менять. Строка в C# не имеет кодировки, изменить её невозможно.